# Issue when using filter function in a dataset

Tags: r, filter

I am working with a dataset composed of transaction (customer purchases) data and I am interested on a specific customer that has purchased 200 items of a certain product and I want to identify the rows that contain this transaction in my dataset. The column I'm performing the filter on is called PROD_QTY and here's the command I'm using:

```
transactionData %>% filter(PROD_QTY > 200)
```

Where transactionData is the name of my dataset.

The issue is that I get the following error *"Error in filter(., PROD_QTY > 200) : object 'PROD_QTY' not found"* .

I have also tried changing the command a bit but I've gotten the same error

```
filter(transactionData, PROD_QTY > 200)
```

After running `dput(head(transactionData))` this is the output:

```
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(17821, 18030, 18036, 17760, 
17761, 18032), class = "Date"), STORE_NBR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 4L), LYLTY_CARD_NBR = c(1000L, 1307L, 1343L, 2373L, 2426L, 
4149L), TXN_ID = c(1L, 348L, 383L, 974L, 1038L, 3333L), PROD_NBR = c(5L, 
66L, 61L, 69L, 108L, 16L), PROD_NAME = c("Natural Chip        Compny SeaSalt175g", 
"CCs Nacho Cheese    175g", "Smiths Crinkle Cut  Chips Chicken 170g", 
"Smiths Chip Thinly  S/Cream&Onion 175g", "Kettle Tortilla ChpsHny&Jlpno Chili 150g", 
"Smiths Crinkle Chips Salt & Vinegar 330g"), PROD_QTY = c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L), TOT_SALES = c(6, 6.3, 2.9, 15, 13.8, 5.7
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fbfdb064ee0>)
```

I would thank any suggestions!

Comment: What does `names(transactionData)` return?

Comment: [1] "DATE"           "STORE_NBR"      "LYLTY_CARD_NBR" "TXN_ID"         "PROD_NBR"       "PROD_NAME"      "PROD_QTY"      
[8] "TOT_SALES"

Comment: are you using `dplyr::filter`?

Comment: Maybe there's a conflict with something else loaded in the R session, try closing and restarting R. Or, like @AlexB says, it's n issue of not having called `library(dplyr)`.

Comment: I forgot to upload the dplyr package in the new session I started. However after running the command I now get the following error "Empty data.table (0 rows and 8 cols): DATE,STORE_NBR,LYLTY_CARD_NBR,TXN_ID,PROD_NBR,PROD_NAME...
"

Comment: Can anybody help please?

Comment: Try `dplyr::filter(transactionData, PROD_QTY > 200)`. If it still doesn't work please add `dput(head(transactionData))`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried the first command,  "  dplyr::filter(transactionData, PROD_QTY > 200)  " and it still gives the empty data.table error. With the second suggestion you made, I don't know exactly where do you want me to add that in, could you specify it to me please? Thanks! :)

Comment: Put this in your R console `dput(head(transactionData))` copy the output and edit your post to add it here. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I think you don't have any value in your data which is greater than 200 in `PROD_QTY`. What does `max(transactionData$PROD_QTY, na.rm = TRUE)` return?

Comment: 200. You have helped me see where my error was. I am missing an = next to the > symbol, now I have entered the command you suggested above and it gives me the output I was looking for. Thanks @RonakShah !! :)

Comment: Great! You can add the solution which worked for you as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After running the following command `max(transactionData$PROD_QTY, na.rm = TRUE)` the output was 200 (maximum product quantity). The issue was the lack of an **equal** symbol in the following command line `transactionData %>% filter(PROD_QTY >=200)`
^
|